# C fgets() to get input until EOF rather than enter twice

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm creating a program that reverses every line of input.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[100];

    while((fgets(c,100,stdin)) != NULL)
    {
        c[strlen(c) - 1] = '\0';
        for(int i=strlen(c); i>=0; i--)
        {
            printf("%c",c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My test input:

```
abc 123
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
```

I can print the first line reversed just fine:

```
abc 123
321 cba
```

But when I start to enter the next line of input, it's next to the reversed input, so the full program run for the test input looks like this:

```
abc 123
321 cbalorem ipsum
muspi meroldolor sit amet
tema tis rolod
```

When it should look like this:

```
abc 123
321 cba
lorem ipsum
muspi merol
dolor sit amet
tema tis rolod
```

As a workaround, I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again after the output to be able to enter the next line of input on its own line, but I don't understand why I need to do that.

Comment: A program to `"reverse the reverse"`? Sounds like you just need a print statement.

Comment: After the `for` loop, `printf("\n");`, or else you'll be entering your next line of input on the same line as the reversed input of the first line.

Comment: You should also ensure that `\n` even is in the string. If `fgets` reads any characters at all, it won't return `NULL` unless an error occurs. This means you could read `Hello<EOF>` instead of `Hello\n<EOF>`. Since `<EOF>` won't be in your buffer, what you'll have read is "Hello", and `c[strlen(c) - 1] = 0;` will result in you printing "lleH" instead of "olleH".

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Post it directly in the question with code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does exactly what it is told to. So if you want a newline character just after the reversed string, use the following just after your `for` loop:

```
putchar('\n');
```

---

And you need to keep in mind that there is no guarentee that `c[strlen(c) - 1]` is a newline character. So, check it before replacing it with a `'\0'`:

```
size_t len = strlen(c);
if(len && c[len - 1] == '\n')
    c[len - 1] = '\0';
```

---

Also, if you are stuck with C89, you might as well need to return a value from `main`. Just add

```
return 0; /* Usually, 0 indicates success */
```

at the end of `main` in order to get rid of the warning:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:8:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Note that `return 0;` is implicit in C99 and above.

Comment: Also missing `return` statement in `main` to avoid warning.

Comment: @jdarthenay Thanks! Added.